# Move and rename files based on their parent folders

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, find

I'm trying to write a Bash function that will find files in a given directory tree and move them to the current folder while renaming them based on their parent folder, but I'm still stuck on the first half of the problem; isolating the names of the files and their parent directories.

Getting a list of these files into a variable is easy enough, but operating on this variable to isolate their folders and then putting them into another variable feels like it's a lot harder than it should be, or I'm missing something stupidly obvious.

```
files=$(find * -type f -iname "*english.srt") 
for i in "$files"; do folders=(${files%%/*}; done;
echo $folders # returns only the name of the first folder
```

I'm running Cygwin on Windows 10, but neither files or folders that I'm testing with have spaces in them.

Comment: The first line assigns almost the whole output of `find` to the variable. In the second line `"$files"` is guaranteed to expand to exactly one word, so the body of the loop runs just once. But even if it run multiple times, `echo` *outside* of the loop would print something just once. And there is unbalanced `(` in your code. Parsing `find` is not necessarily a good idea; `find … -exec …` may be. Alternatively in Bash: `shopt -s globstar` and `for f in **/*english.srt`, totally without `find`. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The unbalanced parenthesis was a copy-paste remnant that I thankfully wasn't actually including in the shell, and good catch on the `echo`, I obviously wasn't thinking. It seems my primary problem is that *`"$files"` is guaranteed to expand to exactly one word*, and that this is what I need to solve. How would I solve this, either with `find` or a `for` loop? Does the problem arise from using a variable for the list of files - would using an array be the more conventional way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more coffee and a few more hours figuring it out, I finally managed to hack together a solution that works. It may not be the best/most elegant/most conventional way to do this, but it is working fine for me, and as far as I can tell it works for files with any file extension (apart from the hardcoded *.srt* in the `find` command):

```
files=$(find * -type f -iname "*english.srt");
read -d ' ' -a file <<< "$files"; # split the results of `find` into a manageable array
for f in "${file[@]}"; do 
 parent=${f[@]%%/*}; # get the name of the file's parent folder
 ext=${f##*.} # get the file's extension 
 mv $f "./$parent.$ext"; # extract the file into the current dir, name it                   
done;                    # the same as its parent folder, then give it             
                         # back its extension
```

I'm now using it successfully in my `.bashrc` like so:

```
function extract_subtitles() {
    files=$(find * -type f -iname "*english.srt");
    read -d ' ' -a file <<< "$files";
    for f in "${file[@]}"; do 
    parent=${f[@]%%/*};
    ext=${f##*.}
    mv $f "./$parent.$ext";
    done;
}
```